# Backend as a Service (BAAS): temporary or long term solution?

Tags: api, app

Right now I'm building an app that relies heavily on Parse.com's products. The app uses nearly all of their features:

- Data storage
- User management
- Push messages
- Analytics
- Crash reporting

There are of course upsides

- Very very fast development: less time to market
- Service reliability
- Free of cost (to a certain extent)
- No server setup

and downsides

- the risk of BAAS shutting down: that would render the app worthless
- what happens to my data

What do you think?

Comment: With regard to losing data, do they have a backup mechanism? If you run that every so often, you would hopefully be able to switch to a different vendor if they shut down.

Answer (score 1):

I am hesitant to provide an answer to your question, since it has a side of general micro economy question that is not really on-topic here at Programmers SE.  But, since the site also allows questions of professional interest to programmers (as far as I remember), I think your question falls into the scope.

I would answer that the general problem you are talking about is called [Vendor lock-in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vendor_lock-in), and the usual solution is to establish standards in the market.

In a more specific, technical sense, you could establish your own "market standardization" by decoupling your software from the BAAS' services through your own API abstraction library.

Comment: I agree with answer, just reminded me of classic xkcd :)  http://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: @mklinker: you are right. Let me remark I meant to "create your own mini-standard and use it while there is no prevalent one", but not "propose your own standard to the world" ... unless you want people throwing that particular XKCD strip to your head :)